# How to find the sum of sequence $ 1+4+4^2+\cdots+4^{X+Y} $?

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics, summation

I see the following sequence and it's:
$$h=1+4+4^2+\cdots+4^{X+Y}=\frac{4^{X+Y+1}-1}{4-1}$$

how we get this sequence?

I know this is a primary question but I confused :)

Comment: Dear @Travis,  I means how get this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an example of a *geometric series*. Let's say we try to sum:
$$S=1+r+r^2+r^3+\dotsb+r^n$$
In your example, $r=4$, and $n=X+Y$.

There is a well known "trick" for solving this. Multiply by $r$:
$$Sr=r+r^2+r^3+\dotsb+r^n+r^{n+1}$$
Notice how this is the same thing as $S$, except without the $1$ at front and with an extra $r^{n+1}$ at the end. In fact:
$$Sr=S-1+r^{n+1}$$
Solving:
\begin{align}
Sr&=S-1+r^{n+1} \\
Sr-S&=-1+r^{n+1} \\
S(r-1)&=r^{n+1}-1 \\
S&=\frac{r^{n+1}-1}{r-1}
\end{align}

$$\fbox{$1+r+r^2+r^3+\dotsb+r^n=\dfrac{r^{n+1}-1}{r-1}$}$$

Plugging in $r=4$ and $n=X+Y$, we get your answer.

Comment: can we say sum is: $((4^{X+Y+1}-1)/3)-1?$

Comment: No. Why do you have the $-1$ at the end? It should just be: $$\frac{4^{X+Y+1}-1}{4-1}=\frac{4^{X+Y+1}-1}{3}$$without any $-1$s at the end. (If you were summing $4+4^2+\cdots+4^{X+Y}$ rather than $1+4+4^2+\cdots+4^{X+Y}$, then sure.)

Comment: you means $4+...+4^X+Y=((4^{X+Y+1}-1)/3)-1 $ am I right?

Comment: Yes. If we were to start with $4+\dotsb$ rather than $1+4+\dotsb$, then you would have to subtract off the $1$. However, in your Original Post, you asked the question _with_ the $1$.

Comment: yes, thankssss so muchhhhh

Comment: @MounaMokhiab You are very welcome!

Answer (score 0):

$$x^n-1=(x-1)(x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}+\cdots+x+1)$$

Comment: would you please add more detail ?

Comment: @MounaMokhiab http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Formula

Answer (score 0):

This is a GP, where $a= $ first term=$1$, $r=$common ratio=$4$

Sum of GP is given by $\frac{a(r^n-1)}{r-1}$

$1+\underbrace{4+4^2+\cdots+4^{X+Y}}$
$1+\hspace{25 pt}X+Y\hspace{30 pt}$=n=Number of terms